# Take a String and Search in Google - Windows 8

Tags: string, windows-8, google-search

I am developing an App for Windows 8 for kitchen recipes. I have a checkbox with some ingredients. After selecting the ingredients the user presses a Button. The goal is to present a recipe with those ingredients included. My idea is to put all the values of the checkboxes on one string and Search it via Google and access one of the link given in the results. Is that possible ? iF SO, How can I do it ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question but I hope this helps:

```
https://www.google.nl/search?q=TEXT%20HERE
```

This will google TEXT HERE

https://www.google.nl/search?q=monkey

This will google monkey

Answer (score 2):

You schould use the Custom Search API
The documentation can be found here:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview

Simply do some REST Magic

Helpful for that is the NuGet Package "RestSharp"

hope that helps